# Obtain a square similarity matrix from a list of words

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, nlp

I am trying to compute a similarity matrix from a list of words of 12k elements.
I am using a wordnet similarity using Sematch tool. With a few words I am using this line of code:

`wns_matrix = [[wns.word_similarity(w1, w2, 'li') for w1 in words] for w2 in words]`

The thing is, this code is ok with a few words but with 12k words would be a very long process, like more than a day.

Is there a lean and faster way to compute a square matrix (12k x 12k) of this similarity scores without create a list of list as I am doing?

I tried this solution:

```
wns_matrix = [wns.word_similarity(w1, w2, 'li') for (w1, w2) in itertools.combinations(words,2)]
```

But still it is really slow!
I hope you can help me

Comment: `wns.word_similarity` is a _very_ slow function. No matter how you arrange your loops, their performance is limited by the function calls. Assuming that the similarity is symmetric, you can reduce the time by a factor of 2 by adding the condition `if w1<w2`. That's all, I am afraid.

Comment: Thanks, but why w1<w2 would reduce the time? And where should i place it?

Comment: Put it in the list comprehension. It will reduce time because the similarity between w1 and w2 will be computed only once, not twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wns.word_similarity` is a very slow function. No matter how you arrange your loops, their performance is limited by the function calls. Assuming that the similarity is symmetric, you can reduce the time by a factor of 2 by adding the condition `if w1<w2`. That's all you can do, I am afraid.

```
wns_matrix = [[(wns.word_similarity(w1, w2, 'li') if w1 < w2 else np.nan)
               for w1 in words] for w2 in words]
```